# Prevent multiple async calls to function

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have a thread setup where I call a `setup()` function:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-queue", qos: .utility)

queue.async {
    self.setup {                
    }
}
```

If the `.async` block is triggered multiple times, I want the `setup()` function to be called either:

- multiple times, just not at the *same* time.

**or**

- one time, with previously unfinished calls being cancelled, and only the last call of the function returning.

Either is acceptable in my case.

Is there a swifty way to accomplish this or is the *only* solution RxSwift?

Comment: Can be synchronized using semaphores, but what is that you actually want to protect from multiple calls at the same time? The function itself or just only a variable you use within that function?

Comment: Could you provide an example using semaphores? It’s the function itself. It uses significant CPU usage so having it called 5 times at the same time results in 500% CPU usage whereas 100% 5 separate times (or better yet, only the last time) is more efficient.

Comment: So what's the problem? That's how your code works _now_ if that's the only way setup is ever called. It's a serial queue so it locks until finished.

Comment: @matt it looks like `setup` itself is asynchronous, so the serial queue isn't helping

Comment: @user14664032 If you only want `setup` to be called once then all you need is a simple Boolean flag. Check if it `true` before you call setup. If it is, just return. If it is false, set it to true and call `setup`. Since it appears that `setup` is itself asynchronous unless you can get it to perform *its work* on a serial queue then you will need to use a dispatch semaphore to prevent simultaneous execution. You could use an `OperationQueue`, which does support cancelation, but cancelling tasks that have already started requires the task to continually check. It isn't the simplest

Comment: The reason a Boolean flag doesn’t work here is because if it’s called multiple times, I want the last time it’s called to be the one that goes through, not the first one.

Comment: Well if you genuinely want this process to be cancellable then that's up to you to make it cancellable. Dispatch queues don't do that. Use Operation instead and add code that checks for cancellation at intervals.

Comment: @matt Looks like this will be the route I have to take. Not a huge deal to decide intervals for this particular function. Provide this solution as an answer maybe with sample code for clarity and applicability to my situation, and I will accept it as a sufficient answer to my original question.